# Performance of map vs starmap?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, python-itertools, cpython

I was trying to make a pure-python (without external dependencies) element-wise comparison of two sequences. My first solution was:

```
list(map(operator.eq, seq1, seq2))
```

Then I found `starmap` function from `itertools`, which seemed pretty similar to me. But it turned out to be 37% faster on my computer in worst case. As it was not obvious to me, I measured the time necessary to retrieve 1 element from a generator (don't know if this way is correct):

```
from operator import eq
from itertools import starmap

seq1 = [1,2,3]*10000
seq2 = [1,2,3]*10000
seq2[-1] = 5

gen1 = map(eq, seq1, seq2))
gen2 = starmap(eq, zip(seq1, seq2))

%timeit -n1000 -r10 next(gen1)
%timeit -n1000 -r10 next(gen2)

271 ns ± 1.26 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 1000 loops each)
208 ns ± 1.72 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 10 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

In retrieving elements the second solution is 24% more performant. After that, they both produce the same results for `list`. But from somewhere we gain extra 13% in time:

```
%timeit list(map(eq, seq1, seq2))
%timeit list(starmap(eq, zip(seq1, seq2)))

5.24 ms ± 29.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
3.34 ms ± 84.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

I don't know how to dig deeper in profiling of such nested code? So my question is why the first generator so faster in retrieving and from where we gain extra 13% in `list` function?

EDIT:
My first intention was to perform element-wise comparison instead of `all`, so the `all` function was replaced with `list`.  This replacement does not affect the timing ratio.

CPython 3.6.2 on Windows 10 (64bit)

Comment: Why not just use `seq1 == seq2` ?

Comment: @Błotosmętek thank you for correction! My first intention was element-wise comparision instead of `all`, which was not obvious from my question:) Really if you substitute `list` instead of `all` the order of times will be the same.

Comment: What Python version? And is this CPython?

Comment: @MSeifert yes, CPython 3.6.2 on Windows 10 (64bit)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are several factors that contribute (in conjunction) to the observed performance difference:

- `zip` re-uses the returned `tuple` if it has a reference count of 1 when the next `__next__` call is made.
- `map` builds a *new* `tuple` that is passed to the "mapped function" every time a `__next__` call is made. Actually it probably won't create a new tuple from scratch because Python maintains a storage for unused tuples. But in that case `map` has to find an unused tuple of the right size.
- `starmap` checks if the next item in the iterable is of type `tuple` and if so it just passes it on.
- Calling a C function from within C code with `PyObject_Call` won't create a new tuple that is passed to the callee.

So `starmap` with `zip` will only use one tuple over and over again that is passed to `operator.eq` thus reducing the function call overhead immensely. `map` on the other hand will create a new tuple (or fill a C array from CPython 3.6 on) every time `operator.eq` is called. So what is actually the speed difference is just the tuple creation overhead.

Instead of linking to the source code I'll provide some Cython code that can be used to verify this:

```
In [1]: %load_ext cython

In [2]: %%cython
   ...:
   ...: from cpython.ref cimport Py_DECREF
   ...:
   ...: cpdef func(zipper):
   ...:     a = next(zipper)
   ...:     print('a', a)
   ...:     Py_DECREF(a)
   ...:     b = next(zipper)
   ...:     print('a', a)

In [3]: func(zip([1, 2], [1, 2]))
a (1, 1)
a (2, 2)
```

Yes, `tuple`s aren't really immutable, a simple `Py_DECREF` was sufficient to "trick" `zip` into believing noone else holds a reference to the returned tuple!

As for the "tuple-pass-thru":

```
In [4]: %%cython
   ...:
   ...: def func_inner(*args):
   ...:     print(id(args))
   ...:
   ...: def func(*args):
   ...:     print(id(args))
   ...:     func_inner(*args)

In [5]: func(1, 2)
1404350461320
1404350461320
```

So the tuple is passed right through (just because these are defined as C functions!) This doesn't happen for pure Python functions:

```
In [6]: def func_inner(*args):
   ...:     print(id(args))
   ...:
   ...: def func(*args):
   ...:     print(id(args))
   ...:     func_inner(*args)
   ...:

In [7]: func(1, 2)
1404350436488
1404352833800
```

Note that it also doesn't happen if the called function isn't a C function even if called from a C function:

```
In [8]: %%cython
   ...: 
   ...: def func_inner_c(*args):
   ...:     print(id(args))
   ...: 
   ...: def func(inner, *args):
   ...:     print(id(args))
   ...:     inner(*args)
   ...:

In [9]: def func_inner_py(*args):
    ...:     print(id(args))
    ...:
    ...:

In [10]: func(func_inner_py, 1, 2)
1404350471944
1404353010184

In [11]: func(func_inner_c, 1, 2)
1404344354824
1404344354824
```

So there are a lot of "coincidences" leading up to the point that `starmap` with `zip` is faster than calling `map` with multiple arguments when the called function is also a C function...

Answer (score 2):

One difference I can notice is the how `map` retrieves items from the iterables. Both [`map`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1179) and [`zip`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/bltinmodule.c#L2508) create a tuple of iterators from each iterable passed. Now `zip` maintains a [result tuple](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/bltinmodule.c#L2437) internally that is populated every time next is called and on the other hand, [`map` creates a new array<sup>*</sup>](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1179) with each next call and deallocates it.

---

*<sub>As pointed out by MSeifert till 3.5.4 `map_next` used to allocate a new Python tuple everytime. This changed in 3.6 and till 5 iterables C stack is used and for anything larger than that heap is used. Related PRs: [Issue #27809: map_next() uses fast call](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/cdb5cee9804a1cdc491c18118a92c4592218a894) and [Add _PY_FASTCALL_SMALL_STACK constant](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/bc08ab4598ef05705fd1172f8be8f47307af96c1) | Issue: https://bugs.python.org/issue27809</sub>

Comment: That would assume that this is 3.6, note that the code in [3.5.4](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.5.4/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1168-L1192) looks different. :)

Comment: @MSeifert I wonder how much slow/fast 3.5.4 implementation was compared to 3.6.2.

Comment: (should be slow till 5 iterables because of heap vs C-Stack access)

Comment: Yes, you're correct. My "research" lead me to the same conclusion.